# How do I plot polygons onto a google map with a Spatial Polygons Data Frame in R?

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I am working in the auckland data set from the spdep package and using ggmap and ggplot2 I am attempting to plot the polygons onto the google map of Auckland, however I can retrieve the google map of Auckland without issue, but plotting the polygons hasn't seemed to work whichever way I try. It has to do with my coordinates being in Northing and Easting format because they don't line up with the coordinates of Auckland.

Spent many hours trying to solve this and looking at examples, but to no avail.

Here is the code I am using (should be reproducible without requiring an external import):

```
## Load Package
library(maptools, quietly = T)
library(spdep   , quietly = T)

## Load auckland.nb
example(auckland)
row.names(auckland@data) = 1:nrow(auckland@data)
auck.df = auckland@data     

## Here is a basic plot that I would like to project onto my google map
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot(auckland)
text(auck.df[,1],auck.df[,2],labels = 1:nrow(auck.df),cex=.6)

## Here is my attempt at that projection
library(ggmap  , quietly = T)
library(ggplot2, quietly = T)
library(rgdal  , quietly = T)
library(RgoogleMaps , quietly = T)

myLocation = "auckland"
myMap <- get_map(location=myLocation, source="google", maptype="satellite", crop=FALSE)

data <- fortify(auckland)

ggmap(myMap, zoom = 10, maptype = 'satellite') +
geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = data,
colour = 'black', fill = 'black', alpha = .4, size = .3)
```

I believe this to be an issue with the coordinates, but I do not know how to convert them correctly. Fortify changes the heading of auckland from Northing and Easting to Lat/Long but this doesn't seem to work - I have attempted many hours on this as I have said and I would greatly appreciate any assistance from the community.

Comment: Auckland is at the coordinates 36.8485° S (lat), 174.7633° E (lng), whereas your `auckland` polygon data contains the coordinates around 54.3 lat, 24.2 lng (see one of the polygons at `auckland@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]` for example). Might be worth checking what `spdep` is actually giving you in the `auckland` data set

Comment: Yes, agreed. The coord data is labelled "Northing" and "Easting". I think the issue is that they need to be converted into Long and Lat data. How do I do that?